# Properly format BigQuery response

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Querying data from a BigQuery project:

```
def post(self):
        lat = self.request.get("lat")
        lng = self.request.get("lng")
        query = '''query'''
        query_data = {
            'query': (query)
        }
        logging.info(query)
        query_request = service.jobs()
        query_response = query_request.query(projectId=PROJECTID, body=query_data).execute()
```

The rows return something similar to this:

```
"rows": [{"f": [{"v": "area name."}, {"v": "example"}, {"v": " 100233"}, {"v": "0.0000"}, {"v": "0.0000"}, {"v": "761"}, {"v": "street name"}, {"v": "50"}, {"v": "City"}, {"v": "25"}, {"v": "Town"}, {"v": "distance value"}]
```

Is there a way I could possible format it to something of this nature?

```
  [{
    "streetName": "street name",
    "streetId": "16833",
    "data": "example",
    "latitude": "0.0000",
    "longitude": "0.0000",
    "areaId": "847",
    "areaName": "area name",
    "townId": "50",
    "townName": "town",
    "stateId": "25",
    "stateName": "City",
    "distance": "distance value"
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the generic API client instead of the Cloud-specific client? (By the latter, I mean the one installed by running `pip install google-cloud`). The latter provides a [`QueryResults` class](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/0.20.0/bigquery-query.html) that has the rows pre-parsed for you.

```
query = client.run_sync_query(SQL_CODE)
query.run()
# insert some job.reload/job.state busy waiting 
print(query.rows)
```

Anyway, I believe the Cloud Python client is recommended. That said, since the original question seems to refer to the generic API client, you'll want to use the `schema` field on your `query` object in addition to the `rows`.

The `schema` will serve as a map that you compare against as you traverse the `rows` object.

I have used the below on a schema that has deeply nested/repeated fields; I don't have any samples, however, for what happens on a REPEATED field that is not a RECORD (e.g. REPEATED STRING or some such). Treat such behavior as undefined.

```py
def merge_schema_to_rows(rows, schema):
  acc = {}
  if isinstance(rows, list):
    return list(map(lambda x: merge_schema_to_rows(x, schema), rows))

  if rows is None:
    return None
  # If a field is a REPEATED RECORD, each entry in that field's f list will only
  # have a v.
  if 'f' not in rows:
    rows = rows['v']

  for i, field in enumerate(rows['f']):
    if schema['fields'][i]['type'] == 'RECORD':
      acc[schema['fields'][i]['name']] = merge_schema_to_rows(field['v'], schema['fields'][i])
    else:
      acc[schema['fields'][i]['name']] = field['v']

  return acc
```

EDIT: Poking around GitHub, I was able to find [a more canonical solution](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/27dcf5aa5ecaee1c06021b788286b68e7b294e46/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/_helpers.py#L94) (i.e., what the Google Cloud client does, which is a more robust, but much lengthier version, of the solution I provided above.)